# Running Laravel 5.1 Task Scheduler in Plesk

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron, plesk, laravel-scheduler

I have uploaded my laravel 5.1 project on Plesk server.
I wanted to run task scheduler in Plesk , i have seen many answers on internet to do so but nothing seems to be working for me.

My Plesk Task Scheduling Interface

[image]

I am running schedule:run command like this

```
 php  /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs/artisan schedule:run 1
```

and in cron style i am adding this

```
 * * * * *
```

so that my cron runs every minute

When I click on run now button I get error

[image: Error is for this line artisan file]

```
 $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
```

I search on internet and i found many solutions saying that it's PHP version issue , it will through error if PHP version is less or equal to PHP v5.4, but my current php version is 5.6.30

I am unable to figure it out what's the exact problem .
Help is appreciated

Note: I haven't added any code yet in Kernel.php file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of 'php' try to use command '/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php'

Answer (score 8):

This way of using command works for me fine

```
 /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php  /var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs/artisan schedule:run
```

This is working properly in Plesk

Comment: Hi I have tried this with php 7.4 but I keep getting the following error: ```Task "/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain_name/project_name/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1" completed with error in 0 seconds.``` Is there a way to understand what the error is?

Answer (score 4):

it is a quite old question but for google visitors, Here a solution with **Plesk in 2022**

[image]

Comment: And still for 2023 :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

**/opt/plesk/php/7.3.14/bin/php** httpdocs/artisan

Answer (score 0):

I've used "Run a command" with this path:

`sh /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN_NAME/httpdocs/OCMS_PROJECT/cron.sh`

and added `cron.sh` file into my project:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN_NAME/httpdocs/OCMS_PROJECT/
export $(cat .env | xargs)
alias php='/var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN_NAME/.phpenv/shims/php'

php artisan schedule:run >> CRON.log 2>> CRON.err
```

This is for octobercms, which is based on laravel. It also solves missing env variables, missing php path and wrong php run directory.